# What trees would be good along a boundary wall and avenue in India?

Tags: trees, plant-recommendations, tropical

I am from the eastern part of India i.e. Ranchi (Jharkhand ). Can anyone recommend some trees I can plant along the boundary wall of a school campus? They should provide good shade, temperature reduction, noise reduction and be fast growing.

We also have a 25 feet wide and 1000 feet long straight road in the campus which can be developed as a beautiful avenue.

What about malia dubai, spathodea, tecoma and tabebuia rosea? Can they serve my purpose?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This sounds like an interesting project. Would you kindly post pictures of both areas?  What are the dimensions of the wall? Do you want the trees outside of it or in the schoolyard? You've given us good information, but more details will help us help you! To add them, press the "edit" button under the question, or click on this [edit]. Our [help] is very useful. Check it out, and If you have any problems using the site, just let us know!

Comment: How much access do you have to water? Would you want evergreen or deciduous, or something that might fruit? All helps with biology or botany lessons.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to to grow fast I'd go with a clumping ornamental bamboo Bambusa chungii or the like.  If you need it higher than 10m go with bambusa oldhamii which grows 25m.  If you really want a tree and can't afford the bamboo I believe Neem is easy to find in India and grows very fast.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Bamboo varieties you can also try [Asoca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyalthia_longifolia)  & [Badam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminalia_catappa) trees.

Asoca will have very little leaf fall through out the year and can grown upto 30 feet tall. They attract very few birds in my observation.

Badam tree attract lot of birds and squirrels but are prone to leaf fall during winters.

Another variety you can try is Ficus Benjamina. Ficus benjamina is ever green and has very little leaf fall. It has thick shade and can attract lot of nesting birds.